# how to convert this code into the switch statement

Tags: java

i want to know how could i can this code into the switch statement

i want to do this if else statement into the switch statement please help me out to find out what i have to do for changing this code into switch statement.

```
if (board[r - 1][c] == ' ' && board[r][c - 1] == ' ') {
        nextRow = r;
        nextCol = c - 1;`enter code here`
        return true;
        }


        // We will try to move the cell up.
        if (board[r - 1][c] == ' ') {
        nextRow = r - 1;
        nextCol = c;
        return true;
        }
        // We will try to move the cell to the right.
        else if (board[r][c + 1] == ' ') {
        nextRow = r;
        nextCol = c + 1;
        return true;
        }
        // We will try to move the cell to the left.
        else if (board[r][c - 1] == ' ') {
        nextRow = r;
        nextCol = c - 1;
        return true;
        }
        // We will try to move the cell down.
        else if (board[r + 1][c] == ' ') {
        nextRow = r + 1;
        nextCol = c;
        return true;
        }

        System.out.println("Error due to Array Bound Index");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You can't. Stick with what you have.

Comment: Are nextRow and nextCol class variables ?

Comment: Correct indentation to improve code readability.

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert it to a switch, because you aren't picking what to do on the basis of a single value, and your conditions are not mutually exclusive.

However, you can convert the four ifs into a loop:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 4; ++a) {
    int dr = (a & 1 == 0) ? 0 : (a & 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1;
    int dc = (a & 2 == 0) ? 0 : (a & 1 == 0) ? 1 : -1;
    if (board[r + dr][c + dc] == ' ') {
      nextRow = r + dr;
      nextCol = c + dc;
      return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not checking the same value with each if-else, so it would not be possible to write with a switch. A switch statement checks one variable to see if it fits given values.

Here is the switch statement documentation for more info https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Nit: switches check an expression, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert this to switch statement because you don't check one value. For switch statements code must be like this:

```
int a = 0;
if (a == 0) {
    ...
}
else if (a == 1) {
    ...
}
else if (a == 2) {
    ...
}
...
```

and switch statement:

```
switch (a) {
    case 0:
      ...
      break;
    case 1:
      ...
      break;
    case 2:
      ...
      break;
}
```